# Screenshot without status bar

Tags: iphone, ios, screenshot, statusbar

I'm trying to take a screenshot using [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010193) code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([self screenshot], self, @selector(image: didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}

- (UIImage*)screenshot
{
// Create a graphics context with the target size
// On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
// On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Iterate over every window from back to front
for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
{
    if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || [window screen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
    {
        // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
        // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        // Center the context around the window's anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [window center].x, [window center].y);
        // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, [window transform]);
        // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                              -[window bounds].size.width * [[window layer] anchorPoint].x,
                              -[window bounds].size.height * [[window layer] anchorPoint].y);

        // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
        [[window layer] renderInContext:context];

        // Restore the context
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}

// Retrieve the screenshot image
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
}
```

But the saved image has the status bar whited out, including the signal, time, and battery. How could I take the screenshot including the content of status bar?
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291110/capture-iphone-screen-with-status-bar-included

Comment: @NitinGohel UIGetScreenImage() is a private method.

Comment: sorry mate i can not understand are you asking me or saying.. ?

Comment: @NitinGohel I read the link. The solution is to using the private API UIGetScreenImage()

Answer (score 1):

Hide the status bar before taking screenshot as follows:

> ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];)

Comment: Erm, that's not what the OP wanted. They wanted to include the contents of the status bar in the screenshot.

Comment: You could do with editing the question title then, since it does read like you want it the other way round.

Comment: @luyuan check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

**(Tested with iOS 7 and autolayout)**

I use the simulator *'take screenshot'* feature combined with some conditional code compilation. By uncommenting a `#define` I can quickly switch to *'take screenshot'* mode for my launch screen

The main trick is to hide the status bar when the `view controller` of your opening screen appears, but with a very long animation, so you have plenty of time to hit the screenshot command in the simulator, which places a screenshot right on your desktop (or take a screenshot on the device if you prefer that).

Using the code below, the status bar disappears immediately thanks to the '`UIStatusBarAnimationNone`', but the 'sliding off screen' is animated over a very long period (5000.0 seconds in the code below). So before the bar starts 'moving' 1 point out of the 20 points in vertical size, you have roughly 5000/20 = 250 seconds to take your screenshot (and some coffee).

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIStatusBarAnimation)preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation
{
    #ifdef kTAKE_LAUNCHIMAGE_SCREENSHOT
       return UIStatusBarAnimationNone;
    #else
       return UIStatusBarAnimationSlide;
    #endif
}

- (void)removeStatusBarAnimated
{
    #ifdef kTAKE_LAUNCHIMAGE_SCREENSHOT
        [UIView animateWithDuration:5000.0 animations:^{
            [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
        }];
    #else
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
            [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
        }];
    #endif
}
```

for more information on taking control of the status bar in iOS 7, check my answer and code here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20594717/1869369

Comment: Thanks for the edit Anindya, I don't know how to msg you personally, so I'll ask my question here : I always have trouble copy/pasting code from Xcode to stack overflow - layout is terrible, however I use the 'insert code button' and then 'paste' my code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution without hiding the status bar, simply use the correct bounds and note that the y offset should be negative, here "map" is the a view that fills the screen below the status bar:
(Code is written inside a ViewController)

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.map.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, -1*(self.view.bounds.size.height-self.map.bounds.size.height), self.map.bounds.size.width, self.map.bounds.size.height);

BOOL success = [ self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```