# Hiding status bar iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7

Can't hide status bar on view controller on **ios 7** device.

Already tried setting through **plist file** and also in **Appcontroller.mm** but still i doesn't hide the status bar

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];//Doesn't help
```

Comment: Here's a complete answer on dealing with the status bar in iOS 7 :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20594717/1869369

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot hide status bar in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Go to info.plist and add two attributes if not present. set "Status bar is initially hidden" to `YES` and set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO`. This will hide status bar for your app.

Comment: Just in case you can't find UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance, it appears as "View controller-based status bar appearance".

Comment: Status bar is initially hidden is a checkbox labeled "Hide during application launch" on the general tab in the project settings in the deployment info section.

Answer (score 4):

That's because iOS 7 has changed the way it deals with the status bar.

Setting `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` on your app Info.plist should work.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue recently. Be sure that you are targeting the correct view controller. Try to hide the status bar in the root view controller. Also, I´m implementing the method `(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden` ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prefersStatusBarHidden)) in my UIViewControllers to hide the status bar. By using this method, you can forward the preferred configuration to a "child view controller". Also, this method works fine in UIViewControllers presented as modal.

Answer (score 2):

```
// for ios 7 
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES; 
}


// for ios 6
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For iPad (iOS 7.0) need to put another value at Info.plist file.

UIStatusBarHidden boolean value YES.