# Hidden StatusBar reappears when SearchBar gets activated

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a simple app with a TableView but without a NavigationBar/NavigationController. The app also has a UISearchController with a SearchBar that is always visible. I tried to hide the status bar with *prefersStatusBarHidden* and that works fine. Until the SearchBar is activated. Then the status bar will appear again.

How can I prevent this and keep the status bar hidden?

```
var cityRepository:CityRepository?
var searchController:UISearchController?

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    self.cityRepository = CityRepository()
    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.searchController!.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController!.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController?.searchBar

    //* Already tried this ....
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

Comment: Do you want it always hidden? You can add an entry to your plist as per something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299214/iphone-ios-status-bar-not-hiding-in-xcode-project

Comment: When I add UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance as false and UIStatusBarHidden as true the status bar is always hidden on any view. That will do but it is not exactly what I had in mind. Would be great to set this per View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

***Swift 3***

To selectively display the status bar, you must implement the following:

Go to the Info.plist, add '**View controller-based status bar appearance**' -> **YES**.  This will give you access to being able to set the appearance based on the state of the **prefersHiddendStatusBar** variable for your specific view.

The settings in Interface Builder are simply for simulated metrics; that is, what displays in StoryBoard objects while using Interface Builder.

Next, you will need to create a way to store your conditional preference: "Do I want to display the status bar now?"  In your view controller, create a boolean variable to hold this preference:

```
var displayStatusBar: Bool = false
```

Then, when you use the SearchController, you must tie into the specific delegate methods that fire when you interact with the searchbar. I recommend using:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
```

and

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
```

In each of those delegate methods, you can set the displayStatusBar variable to true or false and then use the **setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()** in each method.  This will force a reload in the status bar.  If you think it looks choppy, throw that code inside a UIView.animate(withDuration:_) completion block for a nice and smooth visual change.

Finally, you need to override the View's preferred status variable and set it to the preference variable.

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return hideStatusBar
}
```