# Hide StatusBar from Window for one view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to remove status bar from window, and add it again. My View is not in view controller's view hierarchy. It is directly added in window. Question is, while this view appear in window, I want to hide status bar from window, When I remove this view, show it again.

```
-(void)hideStatusBarFromWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{
    //.......
}
```

**Note:** I've searched lot, but I've found answered for only view which is added from view controller's view hierarchy. That is my view will show up independent with any of View controller. That means, I couldn't write any code in any view controller and couldn't category view controller.

I've tried this, but couldn't worked for IOS 7(only working for IOS 6)..

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: @NitinGohel please read my question fully. Then go ahead with mark as duplicate.

Comment: @Mani - [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]; this is working for me.. with UIImageView that stored on window. as splash screen..

Comment: In IOS 7, It didn't work for me. In which device, you've tested.

Comment: what is this **otherwise don't look at any question**.

Comment: If you haven't explaination for downvoting , then why do you look at question.

Comment: here in stack overflow NO any rules like that. you can't talking like that. here anybody can down-vote who fill that question not fully suitable. or you never said like dont look at question. very  rude behave.

Comment: Also there is NO any rule like that. It is not rude behave, I'm just asking suggestion for downvotting. If you don't have comment for downvotting, then why do you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try with following code: If you custom view is display at the time of app launch then this code is perfectly working for you other wise you need to manage code *(`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];`)* as per your requirement.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    .
    .
    .
    return YES;
}
```

remove it;.

```
-(void) removeMycustomView
{
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but doesn't worked for me.

Comment: when your custom view is display? i mean at the time of app launch or ..?

Comment: No. It will add to hierarchy after app launch.

Comment: @Mani - may be in ios 7 hide status bar  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971496/hiding-status-bar-ios-7

Comment: Read @Sunny Shah's answer comments.

Answer (score 0):

In info plist add new row

```
View controller-based status bar appearance=NO
```

Comment: Did you read my question fully? I don't want hide status bar for my entire app, but just for an view which is not related with view controller.

Comment: But after that setStatusBarHidden:No and setStatusBarHidden:YES will work. so you can hide or show when you needed

Comment: Couldn't code like this. I think, it's not correct way.

Comment: there is no other way to do this. if you find the correct way then let  me know.

Comment: Sure. I'll let you know. Otherwise, I'll give correct credit you.

Comment: @Mani - this will not hide for entire app.. just try with it.

Comment: if you setStatusBarHidden:YES this will hide from the entire app.if you setStatusBarHidden:NO this will show from the entire app.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this in your view controller.m

```
 -(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
  return isStatusBarHidden;
}

-(IBAction)showHideStatusBar
{
  isStatusBarHidden = (isStatusBarHidden)?NO:YES;
  [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
```

Comment: is this not working too, I have tried before post it here and it's work for me.

Comment: Read my question, above is not my case. If view related with VC, I can write this code on particular VC.

Comment: Now try my updated answer, here isStatusBarHidden is BOOL in view controller.h

Comment: `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` what is this?

Comment: Is this working or not.

Comment: look at here --->  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate

Comment: If view related with VC, I can write this code on particular VC. But view is not related with any VC.

Answer (score -2):

put this method in your viewcontroller.m file

```
  -(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
  {
     return YES;
  }
```

Comment: See Comments with Anand K's.