# In iOS can you guarantee the status bar is hidden?

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm using React Native. I haven't done iOS stuff in a while, I remember in the pre React Native days (or rather, older versions of iOS) you didn't have as much control over the status bar. But now, it's easy-pz. I can easily get rid of it.

The reason I'm asking is because if I can guarantee it's gone, I don't see why keep it all, and I'll just use the space to move the nav bar up and give more space to the content.

Perhaps someone would like to enlighten me.

Comment: Yes,  you can hide status bar from app.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971496/hiding-status-bar-ios-7

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a complete control over the status bar.

You can easily hide it.

Check the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html#content) for more information on the matter.

Comment: I know; but can the OS ever force it to show again?

Comment: @faceyspacey.com Not sure but maybe when sharing your connection (blue status bar) or during a call (green status bar). Can't answer with absolute certainty this one right now.

Answer (score 0):

simple add this to your render function:

```
<StatusBar hidden={true}/>
```