# Swift 3 hide status bar after ViewController init

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

I have a UIViewcontroller sub-class with the following properties:

```
    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return .slide
    }
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return false
    }
```

And would like to change preferStatusBarHidden to true based on method calls, after view controller init. I am unable to change it to true (it's get only).

I think I'm missing something silly here...

Edit:
This is not a duplicate from other hide status bar questions because it involves a property override and computation to determine the property after the view controller has already been presented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding status bar iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971496/hiding-status-bar-ios-7)

Comment: @brimstone this is not a duplicate, the properties in the question didn't even exist in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your logic for when the status bar should be hidden inside the getter for `prefersStatusBarHidden` (where you currently just have `return false`). Then, when you need to trigger an update, call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`.