# IOS 7 Status bar keeps appearing

Tags: ios, iphone

I have used the two methods to remove the status bar ( the one with the time and the signal strength )but it keeps reappearing in my app for IOS 7

I have used the  ' **hide during application launch** ' in GENERAL SETTINGS

I have added the ' **status bar is initially hidden**' BOOL to YES

I have changed the status bar to NONE in every View Controller

---

The problem occurs when i return after having accessed the IPHONE photo library to import a picture into my APP , and only then , it seems to override any previous entries in the PLIST

Does anyone have any code to permanently disable this status bar so it does not appear?

Thanks

*** I have tried all the options listed but still when my app returns from opening and selecting from the photo gallery the status bar re-appears ***

Comment: You have to hide the status bar programmatically in your coding when u come back to your application from photo picker.

Comment: Did you search before asking ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975869/ios-storyboard-disable-status-bar-on-storyboard-once/20594717#20594717

Comment: yes Jan, I did search and so have implemented the changes above , but it was strange as it only re-occurs after I have accessed the photo library..if I don't access that the app is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need implement 2 steps for to hide status bar accross your app:

1) didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES];

    .......

}
```

2) And .plist file of your project
[image: Set this parameter in .plist file]

Comment: Just used the [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES]; after the app had chosen images from the library. Seems it was inheriting the view from the photo gallery..thanks bhavya for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Add method in your view controller implementation.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of this by adding an entry in the .plist file of your project 
"View controller-based status bar appearance" set its boolean value to "NO"